# Arduino Leonardo Firebase

Tags: arduino

Buenas estoy usando una placa Arduino Leonardo, y un modulo esp-8266, y tengo problemas con la librería de FirebaseArduino.h me lanza el siguiente error:

```
Arduino:1.8.3 (Windows 10), Tarjeta:"Arduino Leonardo"

In file included from C:\Users\Mario\Documents\Arduino\Fire_base\Fire_base.ino:1:0:

C:\Users\Mario\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src/FirebaseArduino.h:20:18: fatal error: string: No such file or directory

 #include <string>

                  ^

compilation terminated.

exit status 1
Error compilando para la tarjeta Arduino Leonardo.

Este reporte podría tener más información con
"Mostrar salida detallada durante la compilación"
opción habilitada en Archivo -> Preferencias.
```

El modulo ESP que estoy utilizando es el pequeño:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y la librería que estoy agregando es la siguiente: [Acá está la librería](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-arduino)

Comment: Parece ser que la libreria FirebaseArduino es solo para las placas ESP8266 y si las importas en otras placas como arduino uno,leonardo,mega... dan error como el que tienes tu.  Quizas aqui encuentres algo. https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=427354.0

Comment: y no existe una manera de trabajar con ese modulo en Firebase???

Comment: Pero estas programando directamente el ESP8266 con arduino? O estas usándolo a través del Arduino Leonardo?

Comment: Pudiste resolver el problema?????

Comment: no, lo que hice fue trabajar la librería sobre el ESP y comunicar con el Arduino, pero por alguna rara razon el ESP derrepente dejo de funcionar con la libreria y nunca consegui ese error

Comment: te recomiendo que no lo hagas a través de la librería de Firebase para Arduino o para ESP8266. Puedes montar tu propia llamada a la API, así evitarás que si se modifica algo en Firebase repercuta en tu proyecto. Aquí te dejo un buen tutorial de [Firebase con NodeMCU (ESP8266) y Arduino MKR1000](https://programarfacil.com/blog/arduino-blog/geolocalizacion-wifi-arduino-nodemcu/).

Comment: Deberías simplemente utilizar el Arduino Leonardo para procesar los datos de los sensores y luego los envías por comunicacion serie al módulo esp8266. El esp8266 simplemente lo utilizas para enviar a firebase.